# Using Swift to record and playback video and sending the video to a server

Tags: swift, ios8, video-capture

I am trying to write an app for IOS 8. This app will be written in Swift. I have looked at some Youtube videos for capturing video and playing video. It seems that I have to use AVKit to do this.

After capturing the video I want to be able to send the video to a server so that it can be accessed by other users of this app.

So my question is how do I get my app to record video, send that video to a server, and also be able to play videos from that server.

Comment: it seems to me that you are asking "could anyone write my whole app for me?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to record a video:

```
func startCaptureVideoBlogFromViewController(viewcontroller: UIViewController, withDelegate delegate: protocol<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>) -> Bool{

    if (UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.Camera) == false) {

        return false
    }

    let cameraController = UIImagePickerController()
    cameraController.sourceType = .Camera
    cameraController.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
    cameraController.allowsEditing = false
    cameraController.delegate = delegate

    presentViewController(cameraController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    return true


}
```

Comment: Could you explain how/why your code works? That'll enable the OP and others to understand and apply your methods (where applicable) elsewhere. Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/284827) and liable to be deleted. — [During review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/11873537)